# What does "st" mean in the context of OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I've seen the term `st` come up a few times when looking at other OpenGL fragment shaders. However, I don't know what it stands for or what it's used for. Here's an example:

```
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution;
```

I can understand that this is converting the pixel coordinates into normalized coordinates of 0.0 - 1.0 instead of 640 x 480 (for example).

I've also seen things like `position.st`.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The common names for the components of texture coordinates are U and V. However, because the next letter used (for 3D textures) is W, that causes a conflict with the names for the components of a *position*: X, Y, Z, and **W**.

To avoid such conflicts, OpenGL's convention is that the components of texture coordinates are named S, T, and R. Thus, you have function calls like this:

```
glTexParameter(..., GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
```

Where `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` refers to wrapping in the S component of the texture coordinate.

Unfortunately, OpenGL picked S, T, and R long before GLSL and [swizzle masks](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling) came around. R, of course, conflicts with **R**, G, B, and A. To avoid such conflicts, in GLSL, the texture coordinate swizzle mask uses S, T, **P**, and Q.

In GLSL, you can swizzle with XYZW, STPQ, or RGBA. They all mean exactly the same thing. So `position.st` is exactly the same as `position.xy`. However, you're not allowed to combine swizzle masks from different sets. So `position.xt` is not allowed.

Comment: LOL What a mess !

Comment: @Michael: What's "mess"y about it?

Comment: The way they name everything. I was so confused until I saw your answer.